# showlabels with theoremref

Tags: theorems, showlabels

I am using the `theoremref` package to make referring to earlier theorems easier but I'd also like to use showlabels so I can display my labels for easier referencing. Is there anyway to make showlabels show  the labels given by `\thlabel`?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 5):

Just add `\showlabels{thlabel}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\usepackage{theoremref}

\showlabels{thlabel}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

The references: \thref{exact,zorn,main}

% replicate the manual's example

\setcounter{chapter}{2}\setcounter{section}{1}\setcounter{theorem}{4}

\begin{lemma}\thlabel{zorn}
Zorn's lemma
\end{lemma}

\setcounter{chapter}{5}\setcounter{section}{7}\setcounter{theorem}{6}

\begin{lemma}\thlabel{exact}
Exact
\end{lemma}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}\setcounter{section}{6}\setcounter{theorem}{3}

\begin{theorem}\thlabel{main}
Main theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]